# Right justify amounts in hledger journal text file

Tags: bash, awk, text, printf, accounting

I have a text file and I'm trying to right-align / justify the amounts (`123.00 EUR`) to a specified column number (say `53`) by stretching the spaces before them appropriately

```
# 2018

; A comment



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet      123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlady | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent      321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                2.50 EUR  ; Bank fee
    assets:bank:eur
```

The output should be

```
# 2018

; A comment



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet       123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlord | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent                 321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                           2.50 EUR  ; Bank fee
    assets:bank:eur
```

It could probably be done with `awk` or `printf` or something but I can't figure it out.

More about the issue in the narrow sense as applied to hledger at [Add option to print with normalized output width · Issue #1045 · simonmichael/hledger](https://github.com/simonmichael/hledger/issues/1045)

Comment: please update the question with your `awk` and `printf` coding attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/^([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+([0-9.]+ [[:upper:]]+)(.*)/,a) {
    $0 = sprintf("%-39s %13s%s", a[1], a[2], a[3])
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
# 2018

; A comment



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet        123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlady | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent                  321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                            2.50 EUR  ; Bank fee
    assets:bank:eur
```

I'm using `%-39s %13s` instead of `%-40s%13s` above to ensure you get a space between the 2 fields even if the first field ended up being longer than 40 characters.

Comment: I've adapted the regular expression in your answer to work with a wider range of cases in the hledger format. I'd update the question with these other cases but then what is fair to do: post an answer myself, crediting yours or editing your answer and accepting it?

Comment: The right thing to do is just accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new followup question if you want to enhance the solution to work with different data and either don't know how to do it or want to post your own answer to that. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```bash
jq --raw-input --raw-output --argjson alignToColumn 53 '
  "\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s+EUR" as $searchPattern |   # regular expression to search for in each line
  if test($searchPattern)                     # test if line contains "xxxxx.xx EUR"
  then match($searchPattern) as $match |      # match "xxxxx.xx EUR"
       sub($searchPattern;
           " " * ($alignToColumn - $match.offset - $match.length) +   # add leading spaces to matched "xxxxx.xx EUR"
           $match.string)
  else .                                      # no match found in line
  end
' file.txt
```

---

A more compact version without the use of "if-then-else":

```bash
jq --raw-input --raw-output --argjson alignToColumn 53 '
  "\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s+EUR" as $searchPattern |
  ( match($searchPattern) as $m
    | .[:$m.offset] + ($alignToColumn - $m.offset - $m.length) * " " + .[$m.offset:]
  ) // .
' file.txt
```

---

**Remark**

If a line contains more then one "xxxxx.xx EUR", the first match is aligned
(see extra line "other stuff" in the output below)

---

**Output**

```
# 2018

; A comment



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet        123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlady | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent                  321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                            2.50 EUR  ; Bank fee
    other stuff                                 7 EUR, 12.34 EUR
    assets:bank:eur
```

Comment: Seems unorthodox to pick `jq` but it works! What are the reasons? If I were to guess,  support for `\d` in regular expressions...

Comment: I like to use `jq` for text processing because you can transform XML, JSON, YAML and any text using the options `-rR` with the same concise syntax.

Answer (score 1):

According to hledger's [manual](https://github.com/trygvis/hledger/blob/master/MANUAL.md), the field separator is ***two or more spaces***.

Also, the lines with an `account` have at least 2 (non-commented) fields and the ones with an `amount` have 3 (non-commented) fields.

You can use this fact for differentiating the lines with an `amount` from the other ones.

Here's an `awk` idea for re-indenting the whole file with a given number of spaces while right-aligning the amounts; it's a little different from what you asked because you don't have to specify the column where you want to move the amounts to, it'll align them according to the biggest account string:

```bash
awk -F ' {2,}|^ +' -v OFS='    ' '
    FNR == NR {
        if ( $1 !~ /^;/ ) {
            if ( NF >= 2 && $2 !~ /^;/ ) {
                account_size[FNR] = length($2)
                if ( max_account_size < account_size[FNR] )
                    max_account_size = account_size[FNR]
                if ( NF >= 3 && $3 !~ /^;/ ) {
                    amount_size[FNR] = length($3)
                    if ( max_amount_size < amount_size[FNR] )
                        max_amount_size = amount_size[FNR]
                }
            }
        }
        next
    }
    FNR in account_size {
        $2 = (FNR in amount_size) ? sprintf("%-" max_account_size + (max_amount_size - amount_size[FNR]) "s", $2) : $2
    }
    1
' file.txt file.txt
```

<sup>**note:** it's a two-pass algorithm so you need to provide the file twice</sup>

```
# 2018

; A comment



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet    123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlady | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent              321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                        2.50 EUR    ; Bank fee
    assets:bank:eur
```

<sup>**remark:** as you can see, the `; Bank fee` comment is considered a field so it got indented with `OFS`</sup>