# Aligning postings to a specific column number in an hledger journal

Tags: bash, awk, text, printf, accounting

This is a follow-up question to [Right justify amounts in hledger journal text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763976/right-justify-amounts-in-hledger-journal-text-file)

[hledger](https://hledger.org/) is a [plaintext accounting](https://plaintextaccounting.org/) CLI program that can output all the postings of a transaction aligned amongst themselves, but not **align the entire journal to a specific column number** (see [Add option to print with normalized output width · Issue #1045 · simonmichael/hledger](https://github.com/simonmichael/hledger/issues/1045))

```
# Test journal

; To test right-alignment of amounts



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet      123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlady | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent      321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                2.50 EUR  ; Bank fee
    assets:bank:eur           -323.50 EUR

2016/01/01 Unit prices
   Expense:Foo  56 @ $6.00 ; a comment after a space
   Cash  $-336  ; a comment after two spaces

2022-01-01 Time
    skill      10000h
    time      -10000h
   weird    ; weird comment on posting without amount

2018-01-01 @Some things in life | Are free
    ; With and without comment
    expenses:misc:stuff                                       0  ; A comment
    expenses:misc:things                                      0
    assets:cash:eur
```

Output should be

```
# Test journal

; To test right-alignment of amounts



* Transactions

2018-01-01 @Payee | Internet
    expenses:communication:internet       123.00 EUR
    assets:cash:eur

2018-01-01 @Landlady | Rent
    expenses:housing:rent                 321.00 EUR
    expenses:fees                           2.50 EUR  ; Bank fee
    assets:bank:eur                      -323.50 EUR

2016/01/01 Unit prices
   Expense:Foo                            56 @ $6.00 ; a comment after a space
   Cash                                        $-336  ; a comment after two spaces

2022-01-01 Time
    skill                                     10000h
    time                                     -10000h
   weird                                            ; weird comment on posting without amount

2018-01-01 @Some things in life | Are free
    ; With and without comment
    expenses:misc:stuff                            0  ; A comment
    expenses:misc:things                           0
    assets:cash:eur
```

So the **spaces have to stretch** between the accounts (indented entries to the left) and the amounts (the text to the right)

Sounds like a job for `awk`, `printf`, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adapted from [Ed Morton's answer to the initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74765525/5266640). The regexp is made more flexible, to cover more of the edge cases possible in a journal file.

Here is how to right-align up to column 53.

align-journal.awk

```
match($0,/^( {2,4}[^ ]+)  +([^;]+\y)?( *;.*)?/,a) {
    $0 = sprintf("%-39s %12s%s", a[1], a[2], a[3])
}
{ print }
```

Running this AWK script on `test.journal`...

```
awk -f align-journal.awk test.journal
```

...produces the desired output. `awk -f align-journal.awk test.journal > neat.journal` to redirect it to a `neat.journal` file.

### Explanations

The regular expression goes something like this: at the start of a line, in the first capture group match 2 to 4 spaces followed by 1 or more of any character that isn't space. Then 2 or more spaces, not captured. This is the space that's supposed to stretch to provide alignment / justification. Then second capture group, this is the amount of the posting, which can have many forms. Match whatever character isn't a `;` (semicolons are how comments start in hledger journals) 1 or more times up to a word boundary. Do this if such a pattern exists. Then the third and final capture group, for the posting comment, if it exists: 0 or more spaces followed by a `;`, followed by anything till the end of the line.

The idea is not to try to match the form of the amount field, so the script will manage to align it correctly whatever it is.

`a` is the variable name for what will hold the capturing groups.

The stretching of the spaces in the middle is done by the `sprintf()` function, [using `printf` statements for fancier printing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html). The format string `%-39s %12%s` is chosen to align up to column 53, so last character of text should be on col. 52, and also to ensure a space is kept between the two fields even if the first is longer than 40 chars. That's why 39 and 12 add up to 51 instead of 53.

The script was tested with gawk 5.0.0.